# Unable to output correct form submission

Tags: php

I'm having trouble getting the actual result of the following drop down to be the form submission, instead of what i select the form data submitted is "choseCharacter: choseCharacter1" therefore my SQL statement won't find anything.

```
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <div id="content">
    <label for='choseCharacter'>Please select a character </label> 
    <select name="choseCharacter" id='choseCharacter'>
    <?php 
    $sql = $database->query("SELECT `character_name`,`userid`,`character_class`,`level`,`health`,`max_health`,`mana`,`strength`,`constitution`,`wit`,`intelligence` FROM `character` WHERE `userid` = '$sessionid'") or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query "); 

        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option value=\"choseCharacter1\">" . $row['character_name'] . "</option>";
        }

    ?>
    </select>  
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

PHP

```
     <?php

 $getCharacter = $_POST["choseCharacter"];
$sessionid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $sql = $database->query("SELECT `character_name`,`userid`,`character_class`,`level`,`health`,`max_health`,`mana`,`strength`,`constitution`,`wit`,`intelligence` FROM `character` WHERE `userid` = '$sessionid' and `character_name` = '$getCharacter'") or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query "); 
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

                    echo "<br><label for='character_name'>Char Name: </label>" . $row['character_name'] . 
                        "<br><label for='character_class'> Class: </label>" . $row['character_class'] .
                        "<br><label for='level'> Level: </label>" . $row['level'] .
                        "<br><label for='health'> Health: </label>" . $row['health'] .
                        "<br><label for='mana'>Mana: </label>" . $row['mana'] .
                        "<br><label for='strength'>Strength: </label>" . $row['strength'] .
                        "<br><label for='constitution'>constitution: </label>" . $row['constitution'] .            
                        "<br><label for='wit'>wit: </label>" . $row['wit'] .
                        "<br><label for='intelligence'>intelligence :</label>" . $row['intelligence'] . "<br>";

                    }
```

Comment: where are you initializing session? and in your Query Pass $sessionid with out '' and same for $getcharacter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `option value` needs to contain the value you want to actually use.

So your line of:

```
echo "<option value=\"choseCharacter1\">" . $row['character_name'] . "</option>";
```

Needs to instead be:

```
echo '<option value="'. htmlspecialchars($row['character_name']) .'">'. $row['character_name'] .'</option>';
```

---

**As a side note (important)**: You should use `prepare` and bind the value coming in on `$_POST["choseCharacter"];` to safeguard against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you so much for your help, i've gotten over a major hurdle today!